# How to create file and put string on it using shellscript?

Tags: file, shell, ubuntu-12.04

I want to create a file in `/usr/share/applications/` and put a string on it.

**What I have so far:**

```
sudo touch /usr/share/applications/test.desktop
dentry="testing"
sudo echo $dentry >> /usr/share/applications/test.desktop
```

But this raise an error `Permission Denied`. What should I do to make it works?

Comment: you need to determine which `sudo` is causing the error message. Copy/paste 1 line at a time to the cmdline and execute it. See where the error is. I bet it is the first line. Are you sure you're setup properly to `sudo` commands. That is a whole chapter in a book ;-) . good luck.

Comment: First and second lines are ok! The problem can be third.

Comment: As an aside, you should always double-quote your variable interpolations. `echo "$dentry"` will preserve whitespace, line breaks, and shell metacharactersbin the variable's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the file using your own pernissions, then `sudo cp` it into place.

The reason the second command doesn't work is that the redirection is set up by your shell, before `sudo` even runs. You could work around this by running `sudo sh -c 'echo stuff >>file'` but this is vastly more risk-prone than a simple `sudo cp`, and additionally has a race condition (if you run two concurrent instances of this script, they could end up writing the information twice to the file).